# PHP sprintf format number similar to number_format

Tags: php, number-formatting

How can I format floats by `sprintf` like I would do by `number_format()`? 
I need

- no decimals
- a dot as thousand separator

With `number_format()` I would do so

```
$number = number_format(1599, 0, ".", ",");
```

The result should be:

```
1599 => 1.500
899.99 => 899
70 => 70
```

Is this possible using `sprintf()`?

Kind regards,
Robert

Comment: did you mean all `,` by `.`?

Comment: I don't think `sprintf` supports thousands separator. Is there any reason why `number_format` cannot be used?

Comment: I think `1599 => 1.500` should read `1599 => 1.599` if I understand the question right.

Comment: @hankyPanky: it's a context thing

Comment: @Veekay: YES - exactly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sprintf('A number: %s', number_format(1599, 0, '.', ','))
```

No, there is no other way. `(s)printf` doesn't have options for adding thousand separators.

Answer (score -1):

you can use :

```
sprintf("%.2f", $val);
```

Comment: This doesn't add a thousands separator (nor change it to '.'). If divided by 1000, it could work for numbers up to one million, but no more: `sprintf('%.3f', $val / 1000)`